# Trace an arbitrary Python command issued in PDB?

Tags: python, debugging, pdb

I know I can use PDB to trace through a module, and that I can execute an arbitrary command from pdb by prepending it with a ! (e.g. `!"foo".upper()`).

Is there some way to combine these functionalities to trace through an arbitrary command executed in the current context? E.g. something like `step !"foo".upper()"` that would let me step through the `upper` method, and then return to the earlier context?

Comment: Not really, you can only step up and down through the framestack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `pdb.runcall`

```
(Pdb) pdb.runcall(func, *args, **kwds)   # e.g. pdb.runcall(myfunc, arg1, arg2)
```

and step through it by (n or s) or set a breakpoint into it

```
(Pdb) b my_module.py:123    # b ([file:]lineno | function) [, condition]
```

and run to the breakpoint by pressing "c".

You can not trace builtin functions like str.upper that you used in your example.

**EDIT**: You asked also for **the current context**:
You can evaluate and debug an expression with a user defined function in the current context. Example:

```
pdb.runeval("[myfunc(x) for x in range(3)]", globals(), locals())
# or with ... some_module.globals())
```

The parameters `globals(), locals()` are important because without them the expression will be evaluated in the `__main__` module context, or directly in the current module context if used without locals(), but not in the current global and local context, as it is usual with `!expression`.